Returning a Value from an external operation in shell script in Linux?
I am writing a shell script in Bash.  Within the Bash terminal I am using "CLI" commands to do some function.  In this example I am creating a model, that if the syntax is correct, will return a hex value which I need to use in the next process within the script.  Here is the start of the Bash script:
#!/bin/sh

I do a ton of CLI commands to populate variables in order to create the new model.  Here is the complete CLI command to create the model:
${CLIPATH}/create model mth=0xd70002 attr=0x1006e,val="${FNAME}" attr=0xd70000,val="${MTL}"

All variables have been populated in previous lines in the script.
After this 'create' command is run it returns the following line:
created model handle =  0x2004332

where 0x2004332 is the return value I need to use in the next part of the script.
How can I capture this value?  The created model handle =  is what always is displayed.  The hex number is what we call the "model handle" of the new model I just created.  I need to "associate" the output of the "create" command to another model handle... but I can't do that until I can place the output (0x2004332 in this example) in a variable to use in the next step.

model_handle=$(create_command | sed 's/.* = //')?

First off, if the code starts with #!/bin/sh then it's not bash, it's sh. There are some differences, but primarily bash provides a richer set of instructions and operations. Generally speaking you would make your script executable (chmod a+rx myScript) and then execute it directly (./myScript), leaving the system to read the script's first line to determine the appropriate interpreter. Furthermore, if you put the resulting executable script in a directory referenced somewhere in your $PATH you can treat it exactly like any other command (myScript).
Next, always double-quote your variables when you use them, so your creation command should be
"$CLIPATH/create" model mth=0xd70002 attr=0x1006e,val="$FNAME" attr=0xd70000,val="$MTL"

(It doesn't matter here whether you use "$CLIPATH"/create or "$CLIPATH/create"; it results in exactly the same thing. Likewise for attr=0xd70000,val="$MTL" and "attr=0xd70000,val=$MTL".)
Next, the crux of the question. You described the part of the output that you want as being the hex value at the end of the string. We can parse this out, stripping whitespace as we go, and assign it to a variable
hexCode=$(
    "$CLIPATH/create" model mth=0xd70002 attr=0x1006e,val="$FNAME" attr=0xd70000,val="$MTL" |
    awk '{print $NF}'
)

echo "The code is <$hexCode>"

The awk command sets its variable NF to be the number of whitespace-separated fields. (For created model handle =  0x2004332 that would be 5.) The resulting $5 references the fifth whitespace-separated field. print does what it says.
